# Get POST values in Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, post

I had an ajax submit (**GET** query). But it makes change in my database, so smart people told me I should use **POST** instead with `{% csfr_token %}`.

GET query:

```
$(document).on('submit','#follow', function(e){
    var $button = $(this).find('button');
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:'/event/{{ event.id }}/',
        data: "add={{ event.id }}",
        success:function(){
             $('#follow').hide();
             $('#unfollow').show();
        }
    })
});
```

**views.py**

```
...
event = get_object_or_404(Event, id=event_id)
user = request.user
    if request.GET.get('add'):
        event.users.add(user)
        event.save()
    if request.GET.get('remove'):
        event.users.remove(user)
        event.save()
...
```

So I added `type:"post",` and `csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken])` to data but I don't know what to use instead of `if request.GET.get('add'):` and `if request.GET.get('add'):`. I tried `if request.POST.get('add'):` but it doesn't work. So how to use that `if` with POST values?

**UPD.**

Ok, what i have now...
**template:**

```
<form id="unfollow" {% if user not in event.users.all %}style="display:none;"{% endif %}>
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ event.id }}" name="remove">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-block">{% trans "Unfollow"%}</button>
</form>
```

...

```
$(document).on('submit','#unfollow', function(e){
    var $button = $(this).find('button');
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:'/event/{{ event.id }}/',
        data: {
            'action': 'remove'
        },
        success:function(){
            $('#unfollow').hide();
            $('#follow').show();
        }
    })
});
```

views.py:

```
def show_event(request, event_id):
    event = get_object_or_404(Event, id=event_id)
    user = request.user
    if 'action' in request.POST:
        if 'action' == 'add':
            event.users.add(user)
            event.save()
        elif 'action' == 'remove':
            event.users.remove(user)
            event.save()
    return render(request, 'events/event.html', {'event':event, 'user':user}
```

No errors, but it doesn't work. `success:function()` works fine but there are no changes in database. Any advice?

I also tried `if request.POST('action') == 'add':` but it didn't help

Comment: It should be there in `request.POST` or `request.body` . Just print those variables and you should find that.

Comment: Note that [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/#ajax) explain how to include the CSRF token as a header in every ajax request, so that you don't need to manually include it in the post data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an object for the data `{add: {{ event.id }}}` instead of encoding it as a string `"add={{ event.id }}"`

Then you should be able to fetch the value from `request.POST` with either of the following:

```
request.POST['add']
request.POST.get('add', 'default')  # use default if key doesn't exist
```

You already have event_id in the url, so you don't really need to set `add={{event.id}}`. It might be better to do something like"

```
{'action': 'add'}
```

Then in your view you can do something like:

```
if 'action' in request.POST:
    if request.POST['action'] == 'add':
        # do something
    elif request.POST['action'] == 'remove':
        # do something else
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is MultiValueDictKayError now, what is wrong?

Comment: That means that the value is not in the `request.POST`. You haven't shown enough information for us to tell whether the problem is in your view or template. See my updated answer, you might want to change your javascript and view slightly anyway.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. I updated my question, can you help please?

Comment: There was a typo in the code. I had written `if 'action' == 'add'` instead of `if request.POST['action'] == 'add'`. It looks like you almost tried the right thing, but you should use square brackets instead of round ones to get dictionary keys.

Comment: still the same... i see in browser POST query with action:"remove" parameter but problem still persists

Comment: Does the `event.users.remove(user)` line run? You can add print statements to your code to see how the if statements evaluate.

Comment: No, it seems `if 'action' in request.POST:` doesn't work. print after this returns nothing

Comment: What do you get if you `print(request.POST)`?

Comment: In that case, you need to debug your JavaScript and see why it is sending an empty post request to Django. I can't spot what the problem is. Hope you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following if QueryDict is empty:

`data = request.data['action']`